# Regex issue with infix expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a Java program that is able to follow the order of operations when infix expressions are entered. To simplify input I've decided it would be best to split the entire String by using a `regex` expression. I've been able to split everything except the `6 3` into their own `String` values in the `splitLine` array.  My SSCCE attempt at this is as follows:

```
    String line = "6 + 5 + 6  3 + 18";
    String regex = "(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])";   //Not spitting 6 3 correctly
    String[] splitLine = line.split(regex);
    for (int i=0; i<splitLine.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitLine[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
6
+
5
+
6  3 //Error here
+
18
```

Expected Output:

```
6
+
5
+
6    //Notice
3    //these
+
18
```

I've tried and tried to modify my regex expression and have been unsuccessful. Could anyone tell me why my regex expression isn't splitting the `6` and the `3` into their own `Strings` in the `splitLine` array?

**Edit:** Just wanted to point out that I am doing this for fun, it is not for any sort of school work, etc. I just wanted to see if I could write a program to perform simple infix expressions. I do agree that there are better ways to do this and if the expression were to become more complicated I would run into some issue. But unfortunately this is how my book recommended I approach this step.

Thanks again for all of the quick comments and answers!

Comment: First, your line is not String - edit your example. Second, Yes you have no operator between 6 3 that would match, what kind of operator do you expected there?

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. You need to write yourself a proper scanner and parser. Don't put this off, do it now, you'll just waste time persisting with this approach.

Comment: @EJP This is exactly what I need. I need every element to be represented by itself in the correct order, so that when I place them into my stacks I can easily perform the mathematical operations.

Comment: @Piro Fixed the issue in my SSCCE. I know there is a space between 6 and 3, I'm not dumb, I'm quite new to using `regex` so something like this my slide between my expressions from time to time. Thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : `(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()]|\\s{2,})`

you can try adding a space in the regex, this will also split when there is 2 or more space as in this case 6 and 3 is separated by space, `6 3` will also be separated. this regex will spit the string if more than 2 space is matched. You can change the minimum number of space as `\s{min,}` in the regex

Comment: IDE giving me an `Invalid escape sequence` error with this regex.

Comment: in java you have to escape using back slash .. try giving \\s{2,}

Comment: Ah wow, I'm not on it today. This is exactly what I was working for. Thanks for the help. +1 and accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following regex would match your current input.

```
\s(\w+|[-+*/()])
```

The gist is to search for a whitespace followed by a word or specific character from your list.

**Output**

```
 6
 +
 5
 +
 6
 3
 +
 18
```

Comment: thx but after reading @EJP's comment I'm inclined to [agree with it](https://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&q=infix+parser&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:nl-be:IE-Address&ie=&oe=). Perhaps regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that maybe?

```
String line = "6 + 5 + 6  3 + 18";
String regex = "(?<=[-+*/() ])|(?=[-+*/() ])";   //Added space to character class
String[] splitLine = line.split(regex);
for (int i=0; i<splitLine.length; i++) {
    if (splitLine[i].trim().equals("")) // Check for blank elements
        continue;
    System.out.println(splitLine[i].trim());
}
```

Or you can split your string on `(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)` to get `6 + 5 + 6` and `3 + 18`.